# Compiler and Interpreter on memory efficiency

Tags: interpreter

I was understanding the concept of Compiler and Interpreter. I researched it on the internet but I found two statement tending to contradiction : 
one is saying --- Interpreter doesn't involve intermediate code and hence memory efficient.

https://www.programiz.com/article/difference-compiler-interpreter

other is saying : an interpreter reads a statement from the input, converts it to an intermediate code, executes it, then takes the next statement in sequence. 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compiler_design/compiler_design_overview.htm

Can anyone please let me know that which one is right and which one is memory efficient?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to code an interpreter. Both options mentioned are possible, with different tradeoffs.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that neither article is right. Both have a very narrow (old fashioned?) idea of what an interpreter is, corresponding to something we might call a "command processor". Moreover, neither article is self-consistent, so attempting to resolve their disagreements is probably a waste of time.

That said, when the programiz reference says "No intermediate object code is generated, hence are memory efficient," I *think* what it means (using its terms) is that an interpreter does translate a statement into intermediate code (note that "Figure: Interpreter" includes a box labelled "Intermediate Code"), but:

1. That code is not *object* code.
2. After executing that code, it discards it, so it never has the code for more than one statement in memory at a time.
3. The interpreter does not produce object code as output.

Given that reading, the two articles more-or-less agree.

But even given the narrow definition of 'interpreter', saying that it's "memory efficient" simply because it holds at most one statement's intermediate code in memory at a time ignores all the memory that the interpreter itself takes up.

Moreover, note that this can only be talking about the memory efficiency of the interpreter itself, and *NOT* about the memory efficiency of any programs it runs.

In short: forget about those articles. [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)) seems like a good place to start.

Comment: yeah you're right. I did'nt notice that figure of interpreter.